# Как работает background в разных браузерах?

Tags: html, css, кроссбраузерность

В IE11 картинку расплющило. В chrome всё хорошо. Пытался менять значения `background-position` и `background-size`

[image: IE11]

[image: Chrome]

```css
.callback {
    background-color: #8387db;
    background-image: url(../img/icons/plain.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 23% 103%;
    background-position: 12% 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена. Дело было в `background-size`. Не знаю как отображают его разные браузеры, но после его удаления всё стало норм.